# finding nested table cell contents - jquery query performance

Tags: jquery, performance

I have a huge table with generated html in each td. The generated html is ultimately just another table inside a container div of class `.cellcontent`. The current jquery for getting the contents of the first cell of that table is too slow. **What is a better/faster way of writing the following?**

```
var contents = $(cell).find('.cellContent>table>tbody>tr>td:first :first-child');
```

This jquery is executed for each cell in a very large table quite often and appears to be a significant performance drain on a page.

Cell is the following:

```
var mainTable = document.getElementById("gridID");
for (var colIndex = startIndex; colIndex <= mainTable.rows[0].cells.length; colIndex++) {
    for (var i = 1, row; row = mainTable.rows[i]; i++) {
        cell = row.cells[colIndex - 1];
    }
}
```

The exact generated html of the cell contents is something along the lines of the following:

```
<td class="staticCol prefItem">
    <div class="P_5_18_2013 cellContent">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!--
                        ***HTML I want***
                        e.g., DIV or P or other markup
                        -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Fwiw, I've refined my answer.  The improved query seems to be about 70% faster than the original (and 59% faster than the other answer), so that hopefully helps you out.

Answer (score 2):

Give those elements a **class name.** when generating the content. Then you can directly target them.

```
var contents = $('.className', cell);
```

Answer (score 1):

most of your selectors aren't needed

```
$(cell).find('.cellContent').find('td:first :first-child');
```

that would speed it up however it's unlikely to be the bottleneck. You nested for loop is more likely to cause the performance problem than the jquery selector.

you could alsochange the loop to

```
$(".gridID>tr>td:nth-child(1n+" + startindex).find('.cellContent').find('td:first :first-child');
```

**note:** You are in the outer loop iterating one further than the last column.

Answer (score 1):

There are several improvements that can be made to this search.  I'll step through them and explain what I'm doing so that this answer can be of use to others applying the same principles.

The first step is to eliminate unnecessary selectors. You don't need to search for a TD that is a child of a TR that is a child of a TBODY that is a child of a TABLE (which is what `table>tbody>tr>td` is doing) as it's understood that a valid TABLE has that structure. The extra selectors are drastically increasing the number of operations you have to run. Just search for the first TD.  Instead of —

```
$(cell).find('.cellContent>table>tbody>tr>td:first :first-child');
```

— elminate the unnecessary selectors to get:

```
$(cell).find('.cellContent td:first :first-child');
```

[See the performance improvement](http://jsperf.com/improved-selector/2).

Selectors are read right to left.  In this query, instead of matching all elements with class 'cellContent', then searching within that set for all first TDs, and then searching within that subset for all first-child elements, the query is first matching all first child elements on the page, then eliminating those that aren't descendants of a first TD, and then eliminating those that aren't also descendants of an element with class 'cellContent'. As you can imagine, this is an expensive operation!

We can force the flow left to right by constructing the query to find first one thing and then search the resultant set for another:

```
$(cell).find('.cellContent').find('td:first').find(':first-child');
```

[See the performance improvement](http://jsperf.com/improved-selector/3).

Finally, using `:first-child` is significantly faster than using `:first`, and the first child of a validly formed TR is always going to be the first TD, so use `td:first-child` instead of `td:first`:

```
$(cell).find('.cellContent').find('td:first-child').find(':first-child');
```

[See the performance improvement](http://jsperf.com/improved-selector/4).

*Without altering the html to increase your target's specificity by giving it a class name or id*, that is as efficient as you can make your query.

You can [test the difference in performance](http://jsperf.com/improved-selector/5) between this final query, the original query from your question, and the query provided in the other answer.